# Calling resource server with JWT returns HTTP 403 by way of Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have two projects.  Both are reactive Spring.  Project one is a combination of a Javascript application and Spring Cloud Gateway for reverse proxying.  The second project is a Spring resource server.

Project one proxies requests from `/api/artists` to project two at `http://localhost:8081/v1/artists`.

If I call the resource server (project two) directly with a valid JWT, the response comes back HTTP 200.  If I go by way of the reverse proxy in project one, and hit `http://localhost:8080/api/artists` with the same JWT, I receive an HTTP 403 from project two, which propagates back through project one.

Here is my Spring Cloud Gateway configuration:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: experience-api
          uri: http://localhost:8081/v1/artists
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/artists/**
          filters:
            - TokenRelay=
```

The HTTP 403 indicates that while the token was valid, it must be lacking some other permission to perform the action.  Though, I'm not sure why it works when I call it directly versus calling it by way of the reverse proxy/Spring Cloud Gateway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After stepping away for a couple days, I realized that my gateway configuration was incorrect.  I realized that the original configuration was proxying requests to `/v1/artists/api/artists`, which doesn't exist on project two, but my security configuration was set up so that `/v1/**` required authentication.  I suspect that is why I saw an HTTP 403 Forbidden before I saw an HTTP 404 Not Found.

I ended up using the below configuration:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: experience-api
          uri: http://localhost:8081
          predicates:
            - Path=/v1/artists/**
          filters:
            - TokenRelay=
```

Note that I removed `/v1/artists` from the `uri` property.  Now, requests to project one at  `http://localhost:8080/v1/artists` are getting proxied to `http://localhost:8081/v1/artists`.  I could have used the `StripToken` predicate filter but it wasn't as clean as this.